# "invalid page number 1" error connecting to database with UCanAccess

Tags: java, database, sqlite, ucanaccess

I am following [this tutorial](http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/Full%20Login%20Example.aspx#), just that I changed the connection to UCanAccess.

I imported all jars, but I am still getting an error, I have no idea what is the problem

The Error

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 invalid page number 1
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:264)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at servlets.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:22)
at servlets.UserDAO.login(UserDAO.java:35)
at servlets.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:39)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And the Code

```
package servlets;


import java.sql.*;


public class ConnectionManager {

   static Connection conn;
   static String url;


   public static Connection getConnection()
   {
     try
     {           

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
          String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/workspaceWeb/LoginExample/src/servlets/usersetup.db";

         System.out.println("blabla");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"UserName", "PassWord"); 
         System.out.println("commecla");

     }

     catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex)
     {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
return conn;

}
}
```

Comment: Umm, "usersetup.db" wouldn't happen to be a SQLite database would it? If so, then there is no way that UCanAccess can open it. UCanAccess can only open Access databases (.accdb, .mdb, or related).

Comment: how can I open then sqlite database?

Comment: nvm found out at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm, didnt knew different databases have different connection methods

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open a SQLite database with UCanAccess, and that won't work. UCanAccess can only open Access databases (.accdb, .mdb, or related). To work with a SQLite database you will need to use something like Xerial's [SQLite JDBC Driver](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.xerial%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sqlite-jdbc%22).